# Assign a datablock to an existing object

Tags: scripting, objects, data-blocks

For example:

```
camera_obj = bpy.data.camera.new("Camera")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", camera_obj)
```

works as expected. But is it possible to create `obj` and `camera_obj` in separate places, then link(is it even the correct term?) them together?

```
camera_obj = bpy.data.camera.new("Camera")
# Much code later...
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", None)
# Much much code later...
obj.data = camera_obj # Doesn't work. What should this line look like?
```

Comment: No it doesn't work that way.  An object with `None` as data is an empty and cannot be converted elsewise to another object type by setting the data.  Nor can you make a mesh a camera or any other type once created.  You can only assign another datablock of same type to an objects data.  I'm sure this has been asked and answered before, but cannot find.

Comment: @batFINGER Thank for your reply. So an object's type is decided when it's created with `bpy.data.objects.new`? And it's decided by what kind of `object_data` is passed to `new`...? Even after reading https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_overview.html and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_api_reference.html several times I'm still confused. What's the relationships between Object, Datablock, and ID? Is ID just a baseclass of all of other subclasses?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.  All the objects in `bpy.data.` collections have ID as a base class.  eg `Object` in `objects`, `Mesh` in `meshes` etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Hopefully I'm starting grasping it!

Comment: Re datablock it is how they are stored in blend file .. see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145906/manipulating-blend-file-text-blocks-with-blendfile-py-crud  .. blendfile.py shows how to read a blendfile datablocks with python outside blender.  Blender visualizes them for us. Python API - lets us create, edit, update and destroy them